# Putextra bitmap issue - FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION

Tags: android, android-intent, memory-leaks, bitmap, camera

I sent the picture from the camera to the other activity. I'm trying to do it with an intent. But I got an error. How can I resolve FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION error.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
byte[] byteBitmap = converttoByte(mNextPageBitmap);
intent.putExtra("bitmap", byteBitmap);
startActivity(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));
```

B.class

```
 if(getIntent().hasExtra("bitmap")) {
 byte[] getByte = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("bitmap");
 mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getbyte, 0, getbyte.length);
 bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), mBitmap); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting a bitmap in a Intent is a bad idea.  There's a maximum byte size on an Intent.  Write it to a file, and pass the filename in the intent.